# yum - If local mirror is down, stop

Tags: centos, yum

I've finally gotten around to creating a local mirror, and due to a 'locked' symlink I can now run yum update on all machines and get them to pull the same packages etc so they are all in sync no matter when yum update is run. The problem I am having now is to ensure only the local mirror is used, as yum appears to default to another mirror, even when I use baseurl. Is it possible to lock down the repo config so yum will only pull from specified mirror, even if it's not available?

Example repo conf:

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
baseurl=ftp://user:pass@repo.example.com/centos/locked/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5

[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
baseurl=ftp://user:pass@repo.example.com/centos/locked/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5

[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
baseurl=ftp://user:pass@repo.example.com/centos/locked/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
```

Comment: is this the only file in `/etc/yum/repos.d`?

Comment: No there are others, for epel, percona, remi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With no extra plugin like rhnplugin, CentOS will look in `/etc/yum.conf` and by default all repositories are located under `/etc/yum/repos.d`. If you edit those files, set `enabled` directive to `0` under all the repositories you want to disable, ei all repositories who are *not* your local mirror, run a

```
yum clean all
```

and then a

```
yum repolist
```

it should display only your local repo.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot. The only repo I have enabled by default is the base centos config. I bet the reason why it's default to another mirror is I didn't clear yum cache like you mentioned.

Comment: Clearing the cache worked. Just wish there was something more verbose I could add to the config file to indicate I do not want to try any other mirrors, other than what I specified.

Comment: I don't know why it would try with any other mirror than those specified in the config file, however, if you want to explicitly check weather your custom mirror is OK before trying I don't know if there is such a thing, but writing a yum plugin for it should be simple enough.